# Eclipse use non-existing jre version to resolve maven dependency of tools.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml, dependency-management

I have very strange error in my pom.xml it looks like:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.3.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Could not find artifact com.sun:tools:jar:1.8.0 at specified path C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_241/../lib/tools.jar
at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolveInternal(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:218)
```

**The main strange thing that:**

**1st** - I have this jar at my Build Path and

**2nd** - at any place I have no any pointer to java1.8.0_241 or jre1.8.0_241 in Eclipse Setting and in my Environment Variable also

At current moment I fix this issue by adding the dependency with path to tools.jar directly to plugin section but I think it is a very ugly solution.
Does anyone know other place where I can look for eclipse setting (adding "-vm JDK path" argument to eclipse.ini didn't help me)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where and when do you get the error message (please describe exactly the steps to reproduce this issue)? If it is when running Maven, the Java JDK/JRE used by Maven is specified in Maven's `settings.xml` file.